# start an application from another

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing two applications, AppA and AppB, and I want to start AppB from AppA.

In AppA, I am using

```
Intent initIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.appB.ActivityB");
```

in AppB, I am adding an intent filter to the manifest file :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.appB.ActivityB"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_init" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.appB.ActivityB" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But I got a java.lang.NullPointerException on the intent...
Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to specify an `Activity` in the `Intent`, even though you are creating a `Intent` meant to launch a package; this is not neccesary. Simply remove the `Activity` from your `Intent` like so:

```
Intent initIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.appB");
```

And then just make sure that you have the following two lines in whichever `Activity` you wish to start when the application is launched:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

They should be already be in there for your main `Activity`, although it looks like you were missing the `android.intent.action.MAIN` intent filter in your ActivityB.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent filter isn't complete for [this API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)):

> The current implementation looks first for a main activity in the category CATEGORY_INFO, and next for a main activity in the category CATEGORY_LAUNCHER. Returns null if neither are found.

So you need to modify Activity B's intent filter to include:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply... but the problem is Activity B isn't the main activity in App B, it is an activity that is meant to be called only through App A. Should I still add the <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> ?

Comment: No, in that case don't use `PackageManager` at all.  Just do `new Intent(this, ActivityB.class)` to create an explicit `Intent` for `ActivityB`.  No intent filter needed at all for it.

Comment: yeah, but how would appA recognize ActivityB.class ? with an import ?

Comment: Yes.  Simple import will do it if it is in your same app.  If it happens to be outside of your app and the other activity exported in the manifest then you'd have to build a `ComponentName` object or use one of the other `Intent` method to set the component to target.

Comment: ActivityB is in AppB, so I added this activity in AppA manifest file, and created my intent withIntent initIntent = new Intent();   initIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.appB", "com.example.appB.ActivityB")); but I got a ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. You'll have to build up a `ComponentName` object with the package and class details of the other app. Or, you can send an intent with a custom action which the other app is filtering on. But, that will leave app b open to other apps activating it as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69851/discussion-between-akari-and-larry-schiefer).